# What is the difference between checking if BLE(Bluetooth low energy) feature is available and trying to use the feature and see if it fails?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wanted to check if an Android device has Bluetooth, and if so, use it. I've got the following two pieces of code for this, and cannot figure out why I would need both (as many blog posts and documentation would suggest):

```
if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
    mState = State.Unsupported;
    return;
}
```

and

```
mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
    mState = State.Unsupported;
    return;
}
```

Do these both do the same thing (except for setting the variable) or is there something subtle that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

From android documentation:

> Android 4.3 (API Level 18) introduces built-in platform support for Bluetooth Low Energy in the central role and provides APIs that apps can use to discover devices, query for services, and read/write characteristics. In contrast to Classic Bluetooth, Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) is designed to provide significantly lower power consumption. This allows Android apps to communicate with BLE devices that have low power requirements, such as proximity sensors, heart rate monitors, fitness devices, and so on.

As you can see Bluetooth and Bluetooth Low Energy has some clear differences. So if you want to use Bluetooth Low Energy you should check whether it is available or not as you do for Classic Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth is two distinct protocols. You could be on a device which has regular Bluetooth (3.x) but not Bluetooth LE. Its also possible that you could be on a device without Bluetooth at all.

In the [Android Compatibility Definition Document](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cdd.html): Bluetooth and Bluetooth LE are 'SHOULD' not 'MUST' for handsets so its possible to encounter a device without that capability.